# Replacing Smarty fetch()?

Tags: php, smarty

Here's the code:

```
include 'Smarty.class.php';
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->assign('variable', $variable);
$content = $smarty->fetch('content.tpl');
```

How can I remove the Smarty and use basic PHP functions?

Can I use *file_get_contents*, will this send $variable to the file:

```
$content = file_get_contents('content.php'); // I've renamed .tpl to .php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch('string:'.$content); with Smarty 3 and above.

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl